# Can't delete Kubernetes object: no kind "GetOptions" is registered

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm getting the following error when trying to delete a StatefulSets on my local minikube cluster

> error: no kind "GetOptions" is registered for version "apps/v1"

I can set the replicas to 0, but that still keeps the StatefulSet alive.

I'm running following version

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.0", GitCommit:"6e937839ac04a38cac63e6a7a306c5d035fe7b0a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-09-28T22:57:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0", GitCommit:"fc32d2f3698e36b93322a3465f63a14e9f0eaead", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-26T16:44:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What does `kubectl get statefulset <statefulsetname> -o=yaml` show?

Comment: Can you try `kubectl delete sts --force --grace-period=1`?

Comment: @Rico It shows output of the deployed statefulset. what part are of it would like to see?

Comment: @AbuHanifa The --force command with --grace-period=1 didn't work either. still throwing out the same exception.

Comment: can you add `kubectl version` in the question?

Comment: `code`    Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.0", GitCommit:"6e937839ac04a38cac63e6a7a306c5d035fe7b0a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-09-28T22:57:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0", GitCommit:"fc32d2f3698e36b93322a3465f63a14e9f0eaead", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-26T16:44:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
   `code`

Comment: @AbuHanifa As you can see the kubectl client and server version are not same. Do you think that could be an issue?

Comment: Yes this could be. If possible update kubectl

Comment: @AbuHanifa Yes with the updated kubectl, i can delete the statefulsets. Thanks!

Comment: Added a answer. If it helps please accept it

Answer (score 1):

It seems your kubectl version and kubernetes version isn't in sync. your kubectl version doesn't know new statefulset version. 
You need to upgrade your kubectl version.